# Large surface texturing (repeatable patterns)

Tags: texturing

Is there any way to avoid visible patterns of a seamless texture on a large surface?[image]

[image]

Comment: what do you mean exactly? seamless would suppose that you want to repeat it! And if it is no repeatable it won't be seamless

Comment: I mean the patterns that show up when i repeat the seamless texture on a large scale. The little waves on the picture above

Comment: if you don't want to see any repetition you need to make a texture as large as your object, if that's what you mean

Comment: If the pattern is one without sharp edges, you could try mixing in a different seamless pattern (or even the same pattern) at a different scale using a Mapping node to adjust the scale.  Probably less easy with a texture with defined edges like your stone wall.  Separately, overlaying a grunge texture may at least distract attention from the repetitions.